# Unresolved Identifier with Bridging Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I am trying to include a Swift file in Xcode with a project set up with Objective-C. I included a Bridging Header with the Objective-C file that the Swift file contains, but it still shows an error 'Use of unresolved identifier'.

Background of my project is that I forked the project FSCalendar from GitHub to make changes for how I would personally be using it via Cocoapods. I made my modifications in the FSCalendarSwiftExample project folder (the blue paper icon) that the pull came with as I was writing in mainly in Swift, but when I push my changes the classes that I made in FSCalendarSwiftExample weren't accessible, so I am trying to put it in the FSCalendar project folder, but I am faced with the issue above.

Thanks in advance for the help! This is my first stackoverflow post so let me know if I need to include any other information.

[Screenshot of my Xcode with code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfwOz.jpg)

Comment: Clean + rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you did add the files by the following steps:
targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> +